# Adding the os module to PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I am trying to use the `os` package with PyCharm. When I follow the IDE's [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html), it doesn't appear on the list.

Why is it? And how else can I install it?

[image: screenshot of adding packages to interpreter]

Comment: `os` is part of [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). It comes with Python installation. You don't need to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Managing interpreter packages dialogue in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#packages) is used for installing packages from a repository, by default from [pypi](https://pypi.org/), see [Available Packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/available-packages.html).

The [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os) itself is part of [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/#the-python-standard-library) and is already included in the [Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter) that you have to create before any additional packages can be added to that interpreter.